# How to prevent function parameter conversion from value to reference type in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

Using C++17, I have a method that takes a `function` with a parameter that must be a reference. Right now, I do not get a compilation error when I pass a lambda taking a non-reference parameter. I want this situation to not compile.

How can I achieve this? Also which implicit conversion kicks in and causes the not intended code to compile?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void
takesRefLambda (function < void (string & t) > f)
{
  string test = "nope";
  f (test);
  cout << test << endl;
}

int
main ()
{
  //this shall fail at compile time, as parameter `q` is not a reference
  takesRefLambda ([&](string q)
          {
              q = "yep1";
          });

  //this shall compile
  takesRefLambda ([&](string & q)
          {
              q = "yep2";
          });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `std::function` takes a reference but when it calls the lambda it can pass the string by value

Comment: It's ordinary lvalue -> rvalue conversion in the body of `std::function::operator()`

Comment: Problem starts when lambda is converted to `std::function`. So only way to fix this is to drop use of `std::function`. I do not think there is a simple solution. Own implementation of `function` which will prevent unwanted conversions is my first idea.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but: This is the most... erm... "interesting" formatting of a lambda I've ever seen. It doesn't look like an accident, so I'm genuinely interested in the rational behind this design choice.

Comment: @sebrockm Sorry to disappoint you. It's an accident. :) I fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::function` is designed to be maximally flexible, converting any arguments as necessary. This is usually what you want with type-erasure after all.

The conversions `std::function` performs are straightforward. Given your signature `void(std::string&)`, `std::function::operator()` is more or less

```
void operator()(std::string& s)
{
    callable(s);
}
```

Which is obviously valid if `callable` accepts a `std::string`.

If you must have an exact function signature, test for it

```
template<typename C>
void test(void (C::*) (std::string&));

template<typename C>
void test(void (C::*) (std::string&) const);

template<typename F>
auto takesRefLambda(F&& f)
    -> decltype(test<std::decay_t<F>>(&std::decay_t<F>::operator()))
{
    // use f
}
```

Comment: Similar to what I had in mind (but wasn't able to write down). Maybe, you need one else for plain function `void(std::string&)`? (I'm not sure about non-capturing lambdas, and plain function might be intended to be supported anyways.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It might be, but OP didn't mention it so I omitted it.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ahq8669P5

Comment: I was about to write my own answer along the same lines. Here is a code that uses function traits for most (all?) callables in C++ to check the argument types: https://godbolt.org/z/xEa3nGGMo

Comment: @joergbrech That's too much metaprogramming for a stackoverflow post for me :P Either way, your implementation can't resolve overloaded `operator()`. You can't deduce the resulting member pointer type, you have to be explicit.

Comment: @PasserBy Ah that's right! Also no function templates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works, but I don't understand it completely. What's this `(C::*)` in the test functions?

Comment: `void (C::*) (std::string&)` is a *pointer-to-member-function* for a member function of class/struct `C` returnng `void` and taking `std::string&` as argument. Every lambda is translated by the compiler to a dedicated class with a call operator, so in this example `C` refers to the lambda.